# How modify the id of the elements of a form generated with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I have an application in Symfony with tabs and load asynchronous with Ajax, so that I can use two forms in the application at a time. I have a form to register users and another to update user data. In the update form, Symfony2 generated form therethrough to create users (UserType), so the id of the elements of forms are the same.

On the other hand I have a function to validate form elements, but when it validates one of these forms, validates the other also to have the same id elements, so no validating each form done right.

For example, using Twig
`{{form_row (edit_form.name)}}` generates me an input with `id = "user_name"` and I need to modify it to the update form  as `id = "update_user_name"`.

Is there any way to change the id attribute in that time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```php
{{ form_row(edit_form.name, { 'id': 'edit_user_name' }) }}
```

If you want get the original id and prefix it, you can try this:

```php
{{ form_row(edit_form.name, { 'id': 'update_' ~ edit_form.name.vars.id }) }}
```

Hope this suits your need.

Comment: Hi @chalasr, that is just what I needed, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @chalasr, I need to change the name of the radio field type (choice), in which I have two options: male or female. From the way you've indicated to me the name is changed to div containing the two input but not to each input. This is the result that I have: `<div id="edit_user_sex"><input id="user_sex_0" type="radio"><input id="user_sex_1" type="radio"></div>` And this is what I need: `<div><input id="edit_user_sex_0" type="radio"><input id="edit_user_sex_1" type="radio"></div>`

Comment: Is this the right way @chalasr? `{{ form_row(edit_form.sex[0],{'id':'edit_'~edit_form.sex.vars.id~'_0' }) }} {{ form_row(edit_form.sex[1],{'id':'edit_'~edit_form.sex.vars.id~'_1' }) }}`

Comment: Ah ... It's a pity that the inputs doesn't inherit the custom id. If it works, you can use it. But if you have to do it for a lot of fields, you should try to do this from the controller by iterating over fields and setting the new id (if you can't change the formtype directly. If you need more info or an example, say me and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi @chalasr, It works, and I need only one form field, so I'll leave it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would drop a brief “how to override the `id` attribute value” from the `FormType` implementation:

Basically:

1. Override `buildView();`
2. Modify `$view->vars['id']`

**Piece of code:**

```
/**
 * We're setting the `id` attr. as e.g. `appointment-3-pack-221`
 *
 * @see parent::buildView()
 *
 * @see \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\BaseType::buildView()
 *      Symfony Form component internals where
 *      the `id` attribute gets its value.
 */
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    parent::buildView($view, $form, $options);

    /** @var Appointment $appt */
    $appt = $options['data'];

    $id = sprintf("%s-%d-pack-%d", $view->vars['id'], $appt->id, $appt->pack->id);

    $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, [ 'id' => $id ]);
}
```

Cheers.